# Scraping data from www.transfermarkt.co.uk using BeautifulSoup - Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I'm beginner on scraping i'm trying to scrape data from this website (using beautifulSoup):
https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/transfers/transferrekorde/statistik?saison_id=alle&land_id=0&ausrichtung=&spielerposition_id=&altersklasse=&leihe=&w_s=&plus=1

Following this incomplete tutorial: https://fcpython.com/scraping/introduction-scraping-data-transfermarkt

More precisely on this website section (basically it's a soccer player list with some history informations):
[image]

First i have recognised the elements i'm interested on like:

- playername
- Value
- age
- season

Second i created 1 object for each of them in order to put all these data into a pandas dataframe.

Here my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd , numpy as np

headers = {'User-Agent': 
           'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}

page = "https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/transfers/transferrekorde/statistik?saison_id=alle&land_id=0&ausrichtung=&spielerposition_id=&altersklasse=&leihe=&w_s=&plus=1"
pageTree = requests.get(page, headers=headers)
pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(pageTree.content, 'html.parser')

Players = pageSoup.find_all("a", {"class": "spielprofil_tooltip"})
Values = pageSoup.find_all("td", {"class": "rechts hauptlink"})
Age = pageSoup.find_all("td", {"class": "zentriert"})
```

Finally while a for-loop i create a Pandas Dataframe with all the information i want:

```
PlayersList = []
ValuesList = []
value_pre = []
rank = []
age = []
season = []
team = []
missing = []

for i in range(0,25):
    PlayersList.append(Players[i].text)
    ValuesList.append(Values[i].text)
    value_pre.append(Values_pre[2*i].text)
    rank.append(Age[(5*i)].text)
    age.append(Age[1 + (5*i)].text)
    season.append(Age[2 + (5*i)].text)
    missing.append(Age[3 + (5*i)].text)
    team.append(Age[4 + (5*i)].text)
    
df = pd.DataFrame({"Players":PlayersList,"Value_post":ValuesList , "value_pre":value_pre , "rank": rank ,  "age":age , "season":season ,  "missing": missing ,    "team":team })

df.head()
```

The result i'm getting is a pandas Dataframe like this:

[image]

**My problem:**
if i put a number>25 on the `range()` within the for-loop i get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-202-326415267fee> in <module>
      9 
     10 for i in range(0,26):
---> 11     PlayersList.append(Players[i].text)
     12     ValuesList.append(Values[i].text)
     13     value_pre.append(Values_pre[2*i].text)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Since the table on the screen shows 25 player by each table page, i can just scrape the first 25 player informations.

***If i go to the second page (see the screen) the url does not change, so how can i control this on python?***

***My goal is to extract all the players (and their informations) within the website.***
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add for example `&page=2` at the end of your url to query second page, so it becomes:

```
?saison_id=alle&land_id=0&ausrichtung=&spielerposition_id=&altersklasse=&leihe=&w_s=&plus=1&page=2
```

Note: I shortened url for readability.

Code explaining how to iterate through pages:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd , numpy as np

headers = {'User-Agent': 
           'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}

# iterate from page 1 to page 10
for pagenum in range(1, 11):
    page = "https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/transfers/transferrekorde/statistik?saison_id=alle&land_id=0&ausrichtung=&spielerposition_id=&altersklasse=&leihe=&w_s=&plus=1&page=" + str(pagenum)
    pageTree = requests.get(page, headers=headers)
    pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(pageTree.content, 'html.parser')

    Players = pageSoup.find_all("a", {"class": "spielprofil_tooltip"})
    Values = pageSoup.find_all("td", {"class": "rechts hauptlink"})
    Age = pageSoup.find_all("td", {"class": "zentriert"})

    print(Players)
```

Comment: You perfectly understood my problem, this was the solution i was looking for. Now how can i use the page=2 parameter on my code to let the for-loop  work for each page of that table? thank you@whispored2001

Comment: See my updated answer. I don't know if it's what are you looking for. Please clarify if needed.